# How to send a photo to a rest service

Tags: curl, jax-rs, photo

What is the best approach to be able to send a photo from the iPhone client to a rest service (jax-rs) and save it from there? This is my current server code:

```
@POST
@Path("/newPhoto/{eventId}") 
@Consumes("application/octet-stream") 
public void newPhoto (@PathParam("eventId") String eventID, 
                      InputStream pict) 
     throws Exception 
{ 
        // save photo
}
```

Is this ok or do you recommend something else? And how can I test this service on terminal with curl command?

Answer (score 0):

It looks good for me. Usually, I would put the InputStream as first param, but I checked and it's OK.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a call to this service using a terminal (curl)?

Comment: I don't even know what curl is. What's cool with REST is that it's agnostic.

Comment: (to Aliens) Something like this:  'curl --data-binary @foo.jpg http://host/newPhoto/1234'

Comment: aside: I tried to post @Aliens but apparently one cannot include more than one ampersat (@) immediately followed by a word in a comment.